# Python's subprocess module can replace scripts in shell in crontab?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am working on a task that should update a user's home directory to some value if it belongs to certain group. So, let's say a user was added to some group X, now his/her home directory should be /home/X. I am supposed to put it to work on crontab, my question is:

Is that a safer approach? Or should I always prefer to code this kind of task in shellscript? I am still not clear if I could always use python to replace shell, because it is simpler to handle it.

If someone has a link with pros of using python over shell and when is truly recommended in a productive cluster, I would thank a lot.

Comment: Since Python is really just running the same shell command, there isn't much of a difference of safety. The argument really comes down to that bash is going to be available everywhere while Python is not guaranteed to be in every single Linux distribution. In my personal experience, a lot of people who insist on bash over python tend to have spent years using it.

Comment: But if it is only one machine and it indeed has a its python version? Red Hat? Because in a few hours I devised a code using grp, pwd, and subprocess modules. With my knowledge of shell so far the only way I could think doing the same thing was using regex (and accessing /etc/groups or /etc/passwd) and could take days. My point is more how Python handles memory usage when calling subprocess.call() in a loop, or if pwd can in some way changes /etc/passwd. I am not sure if I was clear here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the python subprocess page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)

> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never
>   implicitly call a system shell. This means that all characters,
>   including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child
>   processes. If the shell is invoked explicitly, via shell=True, it is
>   the application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and
>   metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell injection
>   vulnerabilities.
>
> When using shell=True, the shlex.quote() function can be used to
>   properly escape whitespace and shell metacharacters in strings that
>   are going to be used to construct shell commands.

Whether you need to use a shell or not depends on how you call it. From [the subprocess popen info](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

So if you can call a subprocess with a list of elements, rather than building a string, and it’s easier for you to do that in python than a shell script it shouldn’t be a problem.

Sorry the links are different versions of python, it seemed clearer but they said similar things, so check the correct one for your version of python.